# Rails gem file error

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am a beginner to Rails. I am trying to deploy an application, built using RoR, but when I try to run `rails s` I get the following error:

> There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.

The contents of my Gemfile are as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

require 'youtube_it'
gem 'sunspot', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_rails"
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'
gem 'sunspot_cell_jars'
gem 'progress_bar'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'


gem 'mysql2'


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'


gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'




gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'turbolinks'


gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do

  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to write

```
gem 'youtube_it'
```

instead of

```
require 'youtube_it'
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is happening on a remote machine where you are trying to install the gems for the first time.

The gem `youtube_it` is not all ready installed in the remote system, so you are probably getting the error

> cannot load such file -- youtube_it

There are 2 ways around it:

- Install the gem `youtube_it` on the remote machine before proceeding, with

  gem install youtube_it
- Remove the `require 'youtube_it'` line from your Gemfile and instead have it as `gem 'youtube_it'`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is

```
require 'youtube_it'
```

shouldn't it be

```
gem 'youtube_it'
```

if you want to install the gem